# heroku angular deployment cannot find dist/app-name/index.html

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, web-deployment

So I'm trying to deploy an angular 6 app on heroku, and I followed these steps:
[this](https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147) and [this](https://medium.com/@shubhsharma10/how-to-deploy-angular-6-app-to-heroku-52b73ac7a3aa).

According to the heroku deployment logs, it says the build was successful. But when I try to access, the web page only returns `Not found`.

When I checked heroku logs, this was the result:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I followed all the steps correctly. So what am I doing wrong/missing here?

Comment: did you make sure you have set the correct  `< base href="" />` during the build , you can use the flag `--base-href <project_name>`   during the build to change the base path

Comment: I have written a article about deployment in Apache server, Some of the points in the article will help you to  solve your issue : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: @JoelJoseph it's as is, I didn't touch it `<base href="/">`